# Jenkins: Repetitive Git Polled Builds (Docker Containers)

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, build

Linux build system.
Jenkins 2.73.2 (jenkins/jenkins:lts Docker image) Git Plugin 3.6.2

Pretty basic setup:

- Restrict where this project can be run (set to name of Docker container upon which builds occur).
- Branches to build: Branch Specifier: "**"
- Additional Behaviors: Advanced clone behaviors: not fetching tags
- Poll PCM: "H/5 * * * *" (Bitbucket can't reach this server over the network to trigger on Git push)

Git Polling Log simply says "changes found":

```
Started on Oct 27, 2017 2:18:58 AM
Polling SCM changes on [node_unavailable]
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision adaec1b1c0e4b83dab922eeb490b2f09a4839d30 (origin/EGN-1489)
Done. Took 1 ms
Changes found
```

Every five minutes this constantly triggers the same build.

```
GIT_BRANCH=origin/EGN-1489
GIT_COMMIT=adaec1b1c0e4b83dab922eeb490b2f09a4839d30
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=adaec1b1c0e4b83dab922eeb490b2f09a4839d30
GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT=adaec1b1c0e4b83dab922eeb490b2f09a4839d30
```

In reading about possible solutions, I tried "Wipe out repository & force clone" option and "Force polling using workspace" option but neither those nor anything else I've tried seems to be working. I also don't have any post-commit hooks or anything special like that.

I'd think this was a pretty basic setup except that it's simply not working. If I bind the Branch Specifier to something like "refs/heads/master" and only poll on one branch it works fine. It's not until I'm trying to build against any commit on any branch that things go haywire.

Thoughts?

Comment: Note that I [filed an issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47701) with the plugin management Jenkins instance and it has just a little bit more information.